# Broken images and Javascript on server. Works locally only

Tags: javascript, html

I know this has something to do with the file paths but I'm not sure what else to do. 
I have tried

```
<script src="/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I originally created this in Dreamweaver, but now am no longer using that. Could that have something to do with it?
I have used this same code before on a remote server and it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagesSRP/photo.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
color: #000;
}
a:hover {
color: #0FF;
}
</style>
<title>Stephanie Rodriguez Photography</title>
<p align="center"><a href="index.html"><img src="imagesSRP/srp4.png" width="500" height="112" alt="Home" /></a></p>
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Gallery</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Families</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Film</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center"><img src="imagesSRP/film2.jpg" width="800" height="520"></p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/StephanieRodriguezPhotography?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="imagesSRP/social_01.png" width="45" height="45" alt="Facebook"></a> 
<a href="https://instagram.com/srodriguezphotography/" target="_blank"><img src="imagesSRP/social_04.png" width="45" height="45" alt="Instagram"></a>
<a href="mailto:stephanie@tampafinancials.com"><img src="imagesSRP/social_46.png" width="45" height="45" alt="Email"></a>
<a href="tel:813-453-9723"><img src="imagesSRP/social_47.png" width="45" height="45" alt="Phone"></a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after careful review of the information that was on the website, we came to the conclusion that the website path was different from the local path. Basically FileZilla stored the images into a different path than the local path.

If your path on the local computer is `images/imagename.jpg` then remember to confirm that the database is storing the images in `images/imagename.jpg`. It has to be an exact match, if not, these issues will happen. Also, you are correct, you always want to stick with relative paths as much as possible don't do absolute paths because if you ever change your domain name, you will literally have to go through every single link that uses the domain name and update them.

Do this: `images/imagename.jpg`
Don't do this: `www.domainname.com/imagename.jpg`

When I suggested to try that, I was referring to trying it for troubleshooting purposes, if you could not access it, that would mean there is an issue in the database, if you could access it, then the issue was in the path name.